# Prerequisite `myphony` of target `mytarget` does not exist when rebuilding - as if myphony was a file

Tags: makefile

My Makefile has been recompiling all my source files even if they haven't changed. I gave it a look with `make -d` and found stuff like this:

```
  ...
  Prerequisite `setup' of target `bin/exception/Exceptions.o' does not exist.
Must remake target `bin/exception/Exceptions.o'.
...
```

Please note that this is what I get *after* `bin/exception/Exceptions.o` has already been compiled.

Now what on Earth does it mean by the prerequisite not existing? I've quite clearly declared it, and marked it as PHONY. This example should produce the same results for you (You should just be able to run this - I've made it produce all the necessary files for you)

```
OBJ_DIR=bin
SRC_DIR=src
OBJS=$(OBJ_DIR)/exception/Exception.o

.PHONY: all

all: $(OBJ_DIR)/app

.PHONY: setup

setup:
    mkdir -p $(sort $(dir $(OBJS)))

# To make the source file for you
$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp:
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    touch $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/app: setup $(OBJS)
    @echo CXX -o $@
    @touch $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp setup
    @echo CXX -c -o $@
    @cp $< $@
```

If I take out the requirement for `setup`, then my program will not recompile unchanged sources as expected.

Why does make think it needs to rebuild?

Comment: It means that file doesn't exist. Which it won't until make builds it (or something else creates it). Is there more of a question here?

Comment: @EtanReisner `setup` is not a file, but a target. The file `setup` will never exist, thus why it's declared phony. It seems to be because of this that make thinks a rebuild is required when in reality, it doesn't need to.

Comment: Ah, so the question is why does make always think it needs to rebuild? Ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Phony targets] should not be [...] prerequisite[s] of a real target file.

That's from the manual section on [`Phony` targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets).

What you are seeing is part of why. make *always* considers a phony target as out-of-date and needing to be rebuilt. As a result (and since the file doesn't exist) that also applies to anything that depends on it.

There are two simple solutions to this problem.

The first is to make `setup` a [Force Target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets) instead of a `.PHONY` target which will allow it to operate normally (it might want to also be an [Empty Target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Targets) too but as long as it is touched at least once it should work).

The second is to make `setup` an [order-only prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/app: $(OBJS) | setup
```

and

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp | setup
```

You could also just make sure that the normal output target recipes create the output directory before trying to use it.

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/app: $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo CXX -o $@
    @touch $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo CXX -c -o $@
    @cp $< $@
```

Comment: This makes sense - nice easy fix too. Interesting shorthand there about `$(@D)` - I'll have to remember that one

Comment: @CJxD There are a few more like that too. See the second half of [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).